# Inverse of singular matrix

Tags: python-3.x

How can one invert this singular matrix? I need to solve a system of linear equation, and I tried with Moore-Penrose inversion, but the solution is not sufficient. Therefore I am looking for another way of inverting this matrix.

```
m1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
A = np.matrix(m1)


[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not sufficient"?

Comment: I need another solution for this matrix, since it has many solutions